# Create Animation using set of Images and sound

Tags: android, animation, audio

I have a set of images for an animation and sound file. but i don't know how create this animation and play sound in background with animation. also i want to change(increase/decrease) the frame rate of the animation as well as sound with seekbar change in progress. please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out these 2 tutorials:

- [How to paint, animate, loop en remove a Sprite](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-paint-animate-loop-and-remove-a-sprite/)
- [How to add sound effect to you game](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-add-sound-effects-to-your-game/)

( Both with a Eclipse project download )

**Addition after comment :-)**

to change the framerate check the Initialize of the Sprite class:

```
public void Initialize(Bitmap bitmap, int height, int width, int fps, int frameCount, boolean loop) {}
```

If you add a sprite like so:

```
AnimatedSprite a = new AnimatedSprite();
b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.openRawResource(R.drawable.explosion));
a.Initialize(b, 120, 160, 24, 20, true);
                          ^framerate
```

Comment: Thanx But i need to change the frame rate of the animation and paralley sound as well on seekar progress change. like i am having 25 separate images in PNG formate 1.PNG, 2.PNG.. 25.PNG these 25 images are correspond to single animation now i want to add sound to this and wants to play the animation and need to change the frame rate of both on the fly...please suggest...

Comment: you can change the framerate of the 1st tutorial. Check the initialisation of the sprite